# how to contains char[] key in Dictonary c#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

Hi everyone i have a same structure:

```
Dictionary<char[], char> MyDictonary = new Dictionary<char[], char>();
```

First value is key, and i want to check my key f.e.

```
 char[] array = currentCharecter(this is a string).ToCharArray();
 bool isContains= MyDictonary.ContainsKey(array);
```

I know that i can't complane `chars[]` by `==` and need to use special method. Equal`==` only compares the references of the two arrays, not their items, it will always return false.

I must to compare the elements of one array to the elements of the other. like method `SequenceEqual` . But i dont understand how to use it on it. Heed help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you not convert the `char[]` into a `string`?

Comment: What is `currentCharecter`?

Comment: string key need to do more correction

Comment: @Enigmativity no i can't find char[] in dictonary

Comment: C# isn't actually picky about what's in a `string`, it will allow any old sequence of bytes (and strings won't be considered finished at the first 0 byte either, like in C). Packing things into a `string` really is the most convenient way of getting what you're after even if you only do that to compare keys; without it you're looking at passing a custom `EqualityComparer` to the `Dictionary` constructor. Converting back and forth is trivial (`new string(charArray)`; `s.ToArray()`).

Comment: @AndrewPilikin - No, I'm asking can you not use a `string` as the key rather than a `char[]`?

Comment: @Enigmativity no i have a data init with char f.e.            MyDictonary .Add(new char[] { char1, char2, char5, char17}, '"abcd'); a big data with it

Comment: @AndrewPilikin - I understand what you have. I'm asking if you can convert the `char[]` into a `string` and use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to define a custom class which defines how to compare two char arrays. You can do this by implementing the `IEqualityComparer<char[]>` interface, like this:

```cs
class CharArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<char[]>
{
    public bool Equals(char[] x, char[] y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(char[] obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (char character in obj)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + character.GetHashCode();
            }

            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Then an instance of this class needs to be passed to the constructor of the Dictionary.
So, the usage would look like this:

```cs
var testDictionary = new Dictionary<char[], char>(new CharArrayComparer())
{
    { "Apple".ToCharArray(), 'A' },
    { "Banana".ToCharArray(), 'B' },
    { "Citron".ToCharArray(), 'C' },

};

Console.WriteLine(testDictionary.ContainsKey("Apple".ToCharArray())); //true
Console.WriteLine(testDictionary.ContainsKey("apple".ToCharArray())); //false
```